# How to create timeslots with pickadate.js?

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I like to create the following dropdown list using the time picker from [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/):

```
Between 10:00-11:00
Between 11:00-12:00
Between 12:00-13:00
Between 13:00-14:00
...
```

I've tried the following:

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
    format: "Between HH:00-HH+1-00"
})
```

But this returns:

```
Between 10:00-10+1-:00
Between 11:00-11+1-:00
Between 12:00-12+1-:00
Between 13:00-13+1-:00
...
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `formatLabel` instead:

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
    interval: 60,
    formatLabel: function(time) {
        var hours =  Math.floor(time.pick / 60);
        return  'Between H:i - ' + (hours+1) + ':i';
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to also show the same format in the insert element once you selected a timeslot? Now it just shows "1 PM" if I select "Between 13:00-14:00".